# Memory Problem using NSData

Tags: iphone, memory, nsdata

this is my code it does not releases memory
it reaches to 60 mb  and application kills

for (int i=0; i<[modelList count] ;i++) {

```
    url=@"http://192.168.0.101/images/projectimages/";
    url=[url stringByAppendingString:[modelList objectAtIndex:i]];
    url=[url stringByAppendingString:@".jpg"];


    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];




    NSData *imageData=[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    destinationPath=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/modelimages"];
    destinationPath=[destinationPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[modelList objectAtIndex:i]];
    destinationPath=[destinationPath stringByAppendingString:@".jpg"];

    [imageData writeToFile:destinationPath atomically:YES];

    [imageData release];
    //imageData=nil;
    //[myurl release];  

    //[imageData release];  

    value=value+divideValue;
    printf("%f\n",value);
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(updateProgressBar)toTarget:self withObject:nil];

}
```

Comment: What's the approximate value of [modelList count]?  In the hundreds or more?

Comment: Both url and destinationPath are autoreleased only after this routine relinquishes control to the runloop.  However, unless the for loop iterates many hundreds of thousands of times, those strings won't add up to 60MB.

Does this code actually get images and write them to your Documents directory?  How may images do you find there?

Answer (score 2):

This is terrible:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(updateProgressBar)toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

Because it:

1. creates a lot of threads.
2. as I expect it updates UI, while it should be updated from main thread only.

I think much better will be to do something like that:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateProgressBar) 
                       withObject:nil // or any object you need to pass
                    waitUntilDone:NO] //
```

And the method you've given as example - it should be run in a separate thread instead. 
In this case you'll have one background thread doing all hard work and it will notify the main thread about user interface updates.